# FabricJS - Preserve events on saving / getting canvas from JSON

Tags: javascript, dom-events, fabricjs

Is there a way to "preserve" events when saving canvas to JSON and then get them bonded back on ***loadFromJSON***

In the link below I've created an element *redBox* and bonded an event "moving" on it. After "restoring" canvas from JSON that event no longer available and it makes sense why...

The problem is, based on requirements, I have no idea what element could be in the JSON and what event was previously applied to it. Basically, I need dynamically apply all possible events on that particular element.

http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/rwdt6rwj/

```js
fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Image.prototype, {
  toObject: function() {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
             sanboxValues: this.get('sanboxValues'),
            imgSrc: this.get('imgSrc')
            }
            // name: this.get('name'),
        );
    },
    ddpLoadImage: function(imgSrc, sanboxValues){
     this.setSrc(imgSrc, function(img){
        const {scaleFactor} = sanboxValues;
        img.scale( 1 / scaleFactor ).setCoords();
        img.set({
          clipTo: function(ctx){
            const {x, y, width, height, scaleFactor} = this.sanboxValues;
            ctx.rect(
                x * scaleFactor - width / 2, 
                y * scaleFactor - height / 2, 
                width * scaleFactor, 
                height * scaleFactor
            );
          }
        });
        image.canvas.renderAll()
    }, {
      sanboxValues,
      imgSrc
   });
  }
});


let store;
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');
const canvasOriginalSize = {
 width: 600,
  height: 600
};

const image = new fabric.Image('', {
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
});

const redBox = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'red'
});


const page = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 300,
    height: 300
});

canvas.add(page);
canvas.add(image);
canvas.add(redBox);
canvas.renderAll();



canvas.on("object:modified", function(obj){
 console.log(obj.target);
});

redBox.on("moving", function(obj){
 console.log('Moving redBox');
});




const scaleFactor = 1;
const imgSrc = ['https://picsum.photos/', page.width * scaleFactor,'/',  page.height * scaleFactor].join('');
const x = 10, y = 7, width = page.width, height = page.height; 

image.ddpLoadImage(imgSrc, {x, y, width, height, scaleFactor});

  
  
  
  
  
$("#save").on('click', function(){
 store = canvas.toJSON();
  console.log(store);
});
    
$("#restore").on('click', function(){
 canvas.loadFromJSON(store, function(){
      canvas.getObjects().forEach((obj)=>{
          if (obj.type === 'image') {
      obj.ddpLoadImage(obj.imgSrc, obj.sanboxValues);
          }
      });
     canvas.renderAll();
 });
});
```

```css
#paper {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" />
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
<button id="save">Save to JSON</button>
<button id="restore">Restore form JSON</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to again attach events to objects. In [loadFromJSON](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromJSON) 3rd arguments which is reviver having object from json and fabric object. Add event to fabric objects.

***DEMO***

```js
fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Image.prototype, {
  toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
        sanboxValues: this.get('sanboxValues'),
        imgSrc: this.get('imgSrc')
      }
      // name: this.get('name'),
    );
  },
  ddpLoadImage: function(imgSrc, sanboxValues) {
    this.setSrc(imgSrc, function(img) {
      const {
        scaleFactor
      } = sanboxValues;
      img.scale(1 / scaleFactor).setCoords();
      img.set({
        clipTo: function(ctx) {
          const {
            x,
            y,
            width,
            height,
            scaleFactor
          } = this.sanboxValues;
          ctx.rect(
            x * scaleFactor - width / 2,
            y * scaleFactor - height / 2,
            width * scaleFactor,
            height * scaleFactor
          );
        }
      });
      image.canvas.renderAll()
    }, {
      sanboxValues,
      imgSrc
    });
  }
});


let store;
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');
const canvasOriginalSize = {
  width: 600,
  height: 600
};

const image = new fabric.Image('', {
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
});

const redBox = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: 'red',
  rectType: 'eventedRect'
});


const page = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  width: 300,
  height: 300
});

canvas.add(page,image,redBox);

canvas.on("object:modified", function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.target);
});

redBox.on("moving", rectMoving);

function rectMoving(obj) {
  console.log('Moving redBox');
};

const scaleFactor = 1;
const imgSrc = ['https://picsum.photos/', page.width * scaleFactor, '/', page.height * scaleFactor].join('');
const x = 10,
  y = 7,
  width = page.width,
  height = page.height;

image.ddpLoadImage(imgSrc, {
  x,
  y,
  width,
  height,
  scaleFactor
});


$("#save").on('click', function() {
  store = canvas.toJSON(['rectType']);
  console.log(store);
});

$("#restore").on('click', function() {
  canvas.loadFromJSON(store, function() {
    canvas.renderAll();
  },function(o,object){
    if (object.rectType == 'eventedRect') {
      object.on("moving", rectMoving);
    }
    if (object.type === 'image') {
      object.ddpLoadImage(object.imgSrc, object.sanboxValues);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#paper {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" />
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
<button id="save">Save to JSON</button>
<button id="restore">Restore form JSON</button>
```